# How can I find the particular file in a Project/Folder in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext

I know that using `ctrl+shift+f` we can find the text in folder we want and simple `ctrl+f` will find the text in a opened file or we can right folder and click on a option `Find in Folder...` to search the text

I am looking for, how can I find the file in a Folder/Project.

Comment: I recommend checking out this great sublime tutorial plugin that will turn you into a SublimeText power user. https://sublimetutor.com/

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use the [Goto Anything](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html#goto-anything) feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows and Linux, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on macOS) and type the name of the file you're looking for. If there are multiple hits, you can select the appropriate file using cursor keys. It also supports powerful operators, that let you jump to specific parts inside a file.

**Examples**:

- `file.js` opens that file
- `:100` jumps to line 100 in current file
- `file.js:100` jumps to line 100 in `file.js`
- `@loadFile` lists all files with classes/functions named `loadFile` (shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS)
- `file.js@loadFile` jumps to a `loadFile()` in `file.js`

Comment: great to know about that `file.js@loadFile` does it work with atom?

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto Not that I know of, but you can jump to a specific line

Comment: When using `<kbd>` tags, it's common to put in the label of the key – hence capital P

Comment: For example Command-P and Command-Shift-P are two different keyboard shortcuts. Better written ⌘⇧P.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using:

- Windows: `Ctrl + P`
- Mac: `Cmd + P`

It works much like ItelliJ's `Shift - 2 times`, with a faster and accurate prediction.